# Getting error while working with AXI DRAW on Inkscape

Tags: 20.04, inkscape, glibc

While working with AXI DRAW control as an extension of AXI DRAW on Inkscape we are getting the following error on Ubuntu 20.04 pc with GLIBC 2.31

```
 [8092] Error loading Python lib '/home/user/.config/inkscape/extensions/AxiDraw_395_LinARM/build_deps/libpython3.11.so.1.0': dlopen: /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.35' not found (required by /home/user/.config/inkscape/extensions/AxiDraw_395_LinARM/build_deps/libpython3.11.so.1.0)
```

Answer (score 1):

`glibc` is an important system package, and you cannot update it without upgrading the version of Ubuntu.

Upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04 LTS should solve the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am very new to LINUX. May I know that whether it will work on my current AARCH 64 based PC with the following 
Is it possible to upgrade to ubuntu 22 on this present system having following space ? 
1./dev/mmcblk2p2  4.2G  3.1G  968M  77% / 
2. /dev/mmcblk2p3  9.1G  3.0G  5.7G  35% /overlay
3.or using the pen drive ?

Comment: You can always perform a fresh installation